# how to scan a flutter project for a specific type programmatically at runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart

A quick qustion, is there anyway for me to scan a flutter project for a specific type [Class, Interface] programmatically at runtime  ?

The ideas is to grip a list of a Class's that have implemented a specific interface(abstract class) by checking all the types in the project.

Comment: Have a look at [dart:mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.7/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html).

Comment: Relevant keyword for theat topic is „reflection“